# Javascript get scroll amount in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll

I have a div that is scrollable that I want to conditionally stop scrolling.

The code is something like:

```
if(theDiv.scrollTop + theDiv.clientHeight + thisScrollAmount > theDiv.scrollHeight)
    StopScrolling();
```

How can I get the amount the scroll scrolled?
(I know that `event.wheelDelta` is typically +-120, but it *seems* the amount that is actually scrolled when one scrolls can be quite different than that.)

**EDIT**
Apologies.  It seems this question is unclear.  I was looking for how much the div *WOULD* scroll if the event was not canceled by it's handler.  I was assuming that it took on different values, but it appears to only take on values +- 120.

Perhaps it should be deleted.

Comment: any/all of those.  preferably 8 and 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //Works pretty good

<style type="text/css">
  #divTest{width:150px;height:200px;overflow:auto}
</style>

<script>
  var  amountCanScroll = 400
  function maxScroll( ){
    if( document.getElementById('divTest').scrollTop > amountCanScroll){
      document.getElementById('divTest').scrollTop = amountCanScroll;
    }
  }
</script>


<body><div id="divTest" onscroll="maxScroll()" >
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
      1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>1<br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The code posted is enough to gety him going. Besides I didn't even know about that site :)

Comment: Attaching jsfiddle demos to your answers will get you lots of up-votes. Trust me (read: look at my rep) `:)`

Comment: Not really, I'm looking for the amount a scroll scrolls.  Everything else I think I've got covered.  Thanks though.

Comment: @user420667 either specify exactly what you want then, because this answer your question, or if you figured it out post your answer and accept it.

Comment: I haven't figured it out.  I am looking to find the exact amount that a scroll event will scroll the page.  It seems to me that in IE it only says +-120, but it actually scrolls more or less depending on how much the wheel moved.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: scroll amount is set from the a browser setting. Also in your your question you asked for scroll amount on a div not on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `onscroll` event and check the `scrollTop` property of that div against your maximum allowed scroll amount (this will be an arbitrary number you'll have to come up with) and if it is more than that, re-set the `scrollTop` of that div to that maximum amount.

Comment: @user I don't get it, so are you trying to limit the scroll to a certain position or are trying to limit (or obtain?) the scroll *speed*?

Comment: The scroll event code appears to get executed before the scroll actually takes place.  I would like to prevent any scrolling that would result in scrolling "beyond the end."  The reason for that is scrolling beyond the end seems to cause scrolling of the window.  I tried cancelBubble and stopPropagation, but they didn't seem to prevent that behavior.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to figure out how much scroll happens in a scroll.  It doesn't appear to be a fixed amount, but event.wheelDelta always appears to give +- 120.